# How to display custom layout on notification android

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I want to display a `BANNER` ad in notification, so to build custom notification i have used these code..

```
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.banner_ad);

            Notification customNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ChannelID")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)

                    .build();
```

and my `banner_ad.xml` code ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/idAdViewNotification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_01"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so here my problem is that to load this ad, i have to process the `AdView ID` through java code. So how can i map the ID of AdView from xml to AdView class in java. How can i get access to the `idAdViewNotification` while building the custom notification

Comment: don't do that its against admob policy

Comment: Ok thnx man, i don't even know that @Hamaz